# SparkSQL: Read JSON or Execute Query on Files Directly?

Tags: json, apache-spark

I have many, large JSON files that I'd like to run some analytics against.  I'm just getting started with SparkSQL and am trying to make sure I understand the benefits between having SparkSQL [read the JSON records into an RDD/DataFrame](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets) from file (and have the schema inferred) or to [run a SparkSQL query on the files directly](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#run-sql-on-files-directly).  If you have any experience using SParkSQL either way I'd be interested to hear which method is preferred and why.

Thank you, in advance, for your time and help!

Answer (score 2):

You can call `explain()` as an action instead of `show()` or `count()` on a dataset. Then Spark will show you the selected physical plan.

[image]

You can find the above picture [here](https://databricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Screen-Shot-2015-04-12-at-8.41.26-AM-1024x235.png). As far as I know there should be no difference. But I prefer to use the `read()` method. When I use an IDE, I can see all the available methods. When you do it with SQL, there could be a mistake like `slect` instead of `select`, but you will get the error first, when you run your code.